# How can I resolve error when trying to open Maven JAR file via cmd: Could not find or load main class, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, javafx, executable-jar, noclassdeffounderror, java-17

I have a JavaFX Maven project and I created a JAR file with the Maven *package* phase. Then, I wanted to open the created JAR file via the command line but instead of opening, a *could not find main class* error is displayed.

The JDK I use is Oracle OpenJDK v17.0.4. My IDE is Intelli Idea.

This is my project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUUOY.png)

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmailSystem</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmailSystem</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo/com.example.demo.Application</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

So, I have this JAR file in my target folder of my javafx maven project:
[My JAR file in the target folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF8HD.png)

This is the command I typed:

```
java -jar EmailSystem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And this is the result of the command line:
[Error message in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiOUt.png)

The error:

```
> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.demo.Application
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

So what is this *NoClassDefFoundError* about? How can I resolve that issue? And why javafx/application/Application ?

I seems so simple wanting to open a JAR file, so can anybody help me out with that humble task? :'D

I'd be really grateful, thank you :)

Comment: There are many difficulties in trying to package JavaFX apps as a single executable jar.  I *do not* recommend it.  See the [packaging info in the JavaFX tab for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx).  Unless you have non-modular dependencies, using jlink via the javafx-maven-plugin with the zip option is much easier and more reliable.

Comment: You should be using [Jakarta mail](https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api), not javax.mail.

Comment: Actually, after reviewing, the Jakarta mail implementation (not api) has been superseded by [angus mail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail/#Download_Angus_Mail_Release), so I guess, use that.  There is an [faq](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail/FAQ.html) which explains (some of) the confusion around the lineage of these libraries.